# Why does my Fedora HD come up as 124GB when it was created to be 700GB in Hyper-V?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, fedora, virtual-machines

Any ideas? How can I tell fedora to use 700GB, and do I have reformat to do this?

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_computer-lv_root
                      124G  3.9G  114G   4% /
/dev/sda1             194M   23M  162M  12% /boot
tmpfs                 995M  320K  994M   1% /dev/shm
```

Hyper-V settings:

[image]

Thank you,

pvdisplay -C:

```
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg_mycomp lvm2 a-   127.29G    0
```

lvdisplay -C:

```
  LV      VG        Attr   LSize   Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  lv_root vg_mycomp -wi-ao 125.36G                                      
  lv_swap vg_mycomp -wi-ao   1.94G
```

vgdisplay -C:

```
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vg_mycomp   1   2   0 wz--n- 127.29G    0
```

Comment: The Linux install is using LVM, so it may be that the space is there but for some reason not allocated to any volume. I suggest that you add the output of the following to your question as it may offer clues: "pvdisplay -C", "vgdisplay -C" and "lvdisplay -C"

Comment: Ran the commands and pasted the output into the question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your disk is a Dynamically expanding disk right?

There is a limit of 127G for this type of disk. More details [here](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/general-virtualization-articles/chapter-2-hyper-v-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hyper V 2008 R2 addresses this issue to use 48-bit LBA making max size of hard drive 2 TB.  Unfortunately some Linux distro's are not seeing it.  The Linux Integrated Components may help but I am not sure.  I am interested in proceeding in the direction you have by using LVM with a bunch of drives (maybe even using the SCSI controller, which does see the entire 2 TB).