# Hyper-V - Creating a large fixed disk - EXTREMELY Slow

Tags: hyper-v, hard-drive, virtual-machines

Hey everyone, after posting another question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/60394/why-does-my-fedora-hd-come-up-as-124gb-when-it-was-created-to-be-700gb-in-hyper-v), it seems I have to create a fixed disk in order to get one 700GB.

I have shut down the machine (which basically has nothing on it), and gone to convert to a fixed disk. It is going EXTREMELY slow - if my calculations are correct at the rate its going it will take ~2 days to complete. Its been going for about 6 hours and its about 10% complete. I'd like to continue setting up my server and start using all of the space.

Is this normal? How can I speed this up???

Thank you,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, when you create a VHD, the creation process zeros out the data as it builds the file.

MS released a [tool to create VHD's](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vhdtool) very quickly which bypasses the zero out process.

### Example

To create a 100 GB VHD, use something like:

```
.\VhdTool.exe /create '.\Virtual Hard Disks\SRV-EXCHANGE_Backup.vhd' 107374182400
```

It will take only seconds to complete.

#### Output

```
PS C:\VMStorage> .\VhdTool.exe /create '.\Virtual Hard Disks\SRV-EXCHANGE_Backup.vhd' 107374182400
        Status: Creating new fixed format VHD with name ".\Virtual Hard Disks\SRV-EXCHANGE_Backup.vhd"
        Status: Attempting to create file ".\Virtual Hard Disks\SRV-EXCHANGE_Backup.vhd"
        Status: Created file ".\Virtual Hard Disks\SRV-EXCHANGE_Backup.vhd"
        Status: Set the file length
        Status: Set the valid data length
        Status: VHD footer generated
        Status: VHD footer written to file.
        Status: VHD header area cleared.
        Status: Complete
PS C:\VMStorage>
```

Comment: To add to Andy's response, the blog entry [Why does it take so long to create a fixed size virtual hard disk?](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/12/10/why-does-it-take-so-long-to-create-a-fixed-size-virtual-hard-disk.aspx) by the Virtual PC Guy, provides some background explanation as to why it takes so long to create a fixed VHD.
`The reason why this takes so long is that when we create a new fixed-size virtual hard disk we take the time to explicitly zero-out all of the disk space that is being assigned to the new file.`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a fast VHDX creation tool consider the [Systola VhdxTool](http://systola.com/blog/14.01.2015/VhdTool-Is-Dead-Long-Live-VhdxTool):
It works almost like VHDTool but for VHDX and even offers compatible command line.

Comment: Why minus this? VHDTool is no longer available; this is a vaild answer.