# Why is my Fedora HD STILL coming up as 127 GB?

Tags: linux, hyper-v, hard-drive, fedora, formatting

After posting [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/60394/why-does-my-fedora-hd-come-up-as-124gb-when-it-was-created-to-be-700gb-in-hyper-v), and [creating a fixed 700GB disk in Hyper-V](https://serverfault.com/questions/62940/hyper-v-creating-a-large-fixed-disk-extremely-slow), when I mount Fedora 11 to a CD and go to install it only shows 127GB of space to write to.

How can I use all 700GB on the VHD?????

Thanks very much,

EDIT: In response to Cristians answer, I have made a SCSI controller, pointed it at the 700GB VHD and booted, now Fedora doesnt see any drive at all:

What am I doing wrong  here???

**EDIT 2: If I cannot make an IDE drive thats > 127GB, and I cant boot on the 700GB SCSI, how can I use this space??? 
If I boot on a small IDE with the SCSI attached, Fedora has no idea that all that space is there. Will this appear after loading the operating system? How hard is it to format a large drive and use it in Hyper-V???**

[image]

lspci output:

[image]

Comment: What disk controller does `lspci` show? The Fedora installer has a shell on second console (press Ctrl+Alt+F2).

Comment: See attached screenshot

Comment: I find it strange that there's no SCSI controller in the listing. Just to double check: are you sure that you've added a disk on a SCSI controller? 

Also, I'm *not* sure about this, but the error might be also caused by the fact that the SCSI drives are available to the guest only after installing some "guest additions". Btw, I've seen people recommending booting from an IDE disk and using the SCSI disk for applications/storage (http://www.virtualization.info/2007/12/hyper-v-will-not-boot-virtual-scsi.html).

Comment: Man, thanks for the information but that is annoying. So in theory I will have to make a small IDE to boot off and then format the SCSI controller within fedora?

Comment: Yeah, or use 3 IDE disks as large as possible (+1 CD-ROM) and then create a PV (Physical Volume) on each disk. Then combine the PVs in a big VG (Volume Group) and use it as you like. Regarding the SCSI disk, I would suggest installing Fedora on an IDE disk and after that the *Linux Integration Components for Microsoft Hyper-V* from https://connect.microsoft.com. You can find it in the "Server" category. You'll also need to register using a Live/Hotmail account. Good luck!

Comment: It seems that that package can also be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=ab7f4983-93c5-4a70-8c79-0642f0d59ec2

Comment: A bit off-topic: you might want to give VirtualBox a try.

Comment: VirtualBox?? I want to create a large drive in Hyper-V and use it for file storage. Surely it cant be this hard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from an [article about Hyper-V](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/general-virtualization-articles/chapter-2-hyper-v-overview.html) (thanks [Ryaner](https://serverfault.com/questions/60394/why-does-my-fedora-hd-come-up-as-124gb-when-it-was-created-to-be-700gb-in-hyper-v/61618#61618)):

> Virtual hard disk specifications are
>   independent of the bus type used to
>   connect to the virtual machine.
>   However, the bus type does impose a
>   size limitation on virtual hard disks.
>   Virtual hard disks connected via IDE
>   cannot exceed 127 GB. Virtual hard
>   disks connected via SCSI cannot exceed
>   2040 gigabytes.

So it seems that *you'll need to use a SCSI hard disk*, instead of an IDE one. You could also try splitting the current hard disk into multiple smaller IDE hard disks.

Comment: Ahhh I see. I have created a SCSI controller and pointed the machine to the VHD, still having problems. I have edited the question.
Thank you,

Answer (score -1):

When you say that Fedora is unable to see the SCSI harddisk, what do you mean by that? At what stage does the Fedora fail to boot?

1. **The boot-loader is unable to boot** - You may see an error message saying that there are no bootable disks. You will need to somehow tell the fake Hyper-V BIOS to boot the SCSI drive.
2. **The kernel is unable to boot** - You see an error message from the boot-loader (grub/lilo). This means that the boot-loader has loaded successfully. You will need to re-install the boot-loader because IDE and SCSI drive parameters may have changed.
3. **The root is unable to boot** - The kernel and initrd loads but the kernel panics complaining about being unable to find root. You will need to edit the kernel parameters for the boot-loader and re-install the boot-loader. You may need to change the root from `/dev/hd*` to `/dev/sd*` instead.
4. **The system is unable to boot** - You see the system starting up but it complains about problems in the midddle. This might be a problem with udev and some of the configuration.

Have you tried re-installing Fedora *after* you made the switch from IDE to SCSI?

Comment: You cannot boot on a virtual SCSI drive, but I want to use the SCSI as storage space.